# Obtaining the ration of $Q:\Delta U:W$ for isobaric process

Tags: thermodynamics

I know the First Law of Thermodynamics:

> $$dU = dQ-dW$$

and I also know the following relations:

$$C_p-C_v= R$$ 
for an isobaric process
$$dQ = nC_p\Delta T $$

Now my textbook states this relation for an isobaric process (without any derivation):

> $$Q:\Delta U:W= nC_p\Delta T:nC_v\Delta T:nR\Delta T = C_p:C_v:R$$

How do I derive this ratio? I couldn't find it's derivation on the net or in another book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a reversible *isobaric* process, you are adding heat to the gas Q and it is expanding at constant pressure P to do reversible work on its surroundings.  So:  $$W=P\Delta V$$

$$\Delta U=Q-W=Q-P\Delta V$$But, from the ideal gas law, $PV=nRT$, so $$W=nR\Delta T\tag{1}$$
and $$\Delta U=Q-nR\Delta T$$

So, $$Q=\Delta U+nR\Delta T$$
But for an ideal gas:  $$\Delta U=nC_v\Delta T\tag{2}$$
So, $$Q=nC_v\Delta T+nR\Delta T=nR(C_v+R)\Delta T=nC_p\Delta T\tag{3}$$
Therefore, from Eons. 1-3, we have:
$$Q:\Delta U:W=nC_p\Delta T:nC_v\Delta T:nR\Delta T$$

Answer (score 0):

I'm showing you the derivation of $\Delta U=nCv\Delta T$.

Consider $n$ moles of an ideal gas kept in a rigid container at initial pressure $P$,volume $V$ and temperature $T$.  Now $\Delta Q$ heat is supplied to gas.Its temperature rises from $T$ to $T+ \Delta T$ whereas volume remains constant.

Work done by gas, $W=0$. From first law of thermodynamics,

$\Delta Q_v=\Delta U$

[image]

Now you can easily find the ratio.

Comment: This is an isochoric process, not an isobaric process.

Comment: Yes I have derived it keeping volume constant.

Comment: At constant volume, the W is zero.